# error when downloading datasus microdata?

Tags: r, economics

I have the following problem when I try to download data from SIH-RD via the /rfsaldanha/microdatasus package

```
Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$NUM_PROC` <character> and `..2$NUM_PROC` <integer>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In utils::download.file(file, temp, mode = "wb", method = "libcurl") :
  cannot open URL 'ftp://ftp.datasus.gov.br/dissemin/publicos/SIHSUS/199201_200712/Dados/RDAC9402.dbc': FTP status was '550 Requested action not taken; file unavailable'
```

Can't understand what the problem is? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the code and it seems you are using an old version of the library, as the URL was changed 1 year ago. Find a way to update your library. **From the library:**

```
# Available dates
    atual_url <- "ftp://ftp.datasus.gov.br/dissemin/publicos/SIHSUS/200801_/Dados/"
    antigo_url <- "ftp://ftp.datasus.gov.br/dissemin/publicos/SIHSUS/199201_200712/Dados/"
```

**Source**: https://github.com/rfsaldanha/microdatasus

**To update:**

```
install.packages("mypackage") #change package name
update.packages()
```

**or from github**

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rfsaldanha/microdatasus", force = TRUE)
```